# android : inflated view with a different orientation than the activity

Tags: android, orientation, layout-inflater

The orientation of my activity is fixed to be landscape. I am inflating 3 different layouts  in this activity over an GLsurface view Only one of this will be visible at a time depending on user actions. One of this layout is a video view. I would like to support both vertical and horizontal playing of video. But for all other views it need to be fixed to landscape. How can i achieve this .

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,instead of inflating three different views in the same activity,I would suggest using 3 different activities in addition to the one base activity.

Edit:Removing the LinearLayout code because that will be redundant.You can just change the orientations and fix them on the events to open the individual views.

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: I cannot use different activities to suit my requirement. setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); solved my problem

Comment: use ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED to support both

Answer (score 1):

In you AndroidManifest.xml activity declaration remove

```
android:orientation
```

tag & add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Now override below function in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    if (!isVideoViewSet)//change orientation to portrait other Views, skip for Video View
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Here using some flag(**isVideoViewSet** in above code snippet) you can check which view is set and Set activity orientation accordingly.